# Help regarding limit problem

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried several times to do it. But I don't even know how to start it. here is the question. $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(|2x-1|-|2x+1|)}{x}$$ Thank you for helping me.

Comment: i don't even reach there yet. I'm stuck at |2x-1|-|2x+1| for this symbol | |, what should I do? does it means anything?

Comment: The definition of $|a|$ is the absolute value of $a$ (or it might be the length of a vector, often with double lines instead of single ones). You might think of it as measuring the distance from zero without regard to sign. Here it means $a$ when $a\ge 0$ and $-a$ when $a\lt 0$. So, for example $|\pi| = \pi$ and $|-e|=e$

Answer (score 2):

If we consider the fact that $x$ is close to 0, we can remove the absolute values to get:

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {|2x-1|-|2x+1|}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {1-2x-2x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {-4x}{x}= \lim_{x\to 0}-4=- 4$

Comment: thanks ellya. But I still don't understand. where does it comes from? lim X->0 (1-2x-2x-1)/x? Can't we just continue with lim x->0 (2x-1-2x-1)/x)

Comment: Because $x$ is small $2x-1\lt 0 $ so $|2x-1|=1-2x $

Comment: okay. now I understand. thank you ellya.

Comment: No worries,  glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

$\rm|x|$ is the absolute value of $\rm x$ and it is defined as: $$\rm|x|:=\begin{cases}
x & \text{if $\rm x\geqslant0$}\\ \rm -x & \text{if $\rm x\lt0$}
\end{cases}$$
When $\rm x\to0$, the expression $\rm 2x-1$ is negative and $\rm 2x+1$ gets positive, (you can plug in $\rm x=0$ to check that), so by the definition of the absolute value: $$\rm \begin{align*}\rm \lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{|2x-1|-|2x+1|}{x}&=\rm \lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{-(2x-1)-(2x+1)}{x}\rm  \\\rm 
&=\rm \lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{-2x+1-2x-1}{x}\\
&=\rm \lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{-4x}{x}=-4\\
\end{align*}$$